# ckeditor on django 2 blog

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I need to add ckeditor in my blog. I did it but it doesn't work. 
I install and add ckeditor in my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'ckeditor',
]
```

Add in models.py:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    ...
```

And I have this:
[image]
OR IT WORKS ONLY IN DJANGO ADMIN?

Comment: I add `{{ form.media }}` in html template. And it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will be to use it as a widget using Form

```
Class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['body',]
        widgets = {
            'body': CKEditorWidget(),
        }
```

And don't forget to load the js in your template :

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

More info from the doc : https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#widget

Comment: I add `{{ form.media }}` in html template. And it works!